# C# Save reference to string variables in array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, reference

I would like to save a reference to strings in array. For example:

```
string x = "x", y="y", z="z";
string array[];
```

I would like that array will save a reference to x,y,z. so, in case I will change the array[0] to "xx" then the x will include the "xx"

Thanks
Moti

Comment: Note: It is not possible to "reference" a variable (except with `ref/out` in parameters, but that is different) in C#; this is different from say, PHP .. (There are ways to perform this task, but not exactly as envisioned.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done. Strings in C# are immutable, meaning you can't change them at all, you can only change string references. And you can't create an array of string references (unless you resort to unsafe code - don't go there).

You need to use some other structure to hold your data. A `Dictionary<string, string>` is a possibility as someone suggest. Or, you can always access the strings through your array.

Answer (score 2):

A string variable in C# is immutable.
But a StringBuilder variable is mutable.

```
StringBuilder sb_x = new StringBuilder("x");
StringBuilder sb_y = new StringBuilder("y");
StringBuilder sb_z = new StringBuilder("z");

StringBuilder[] array = { sb_x, sb_y, sb_z };
array[0].Append("x");
```

Now array[0] = "xx" and sb_x is also "xx"!

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of types in the C# type system "value types" and "reference types".

Value types are copied by value. when you copy one, you get an entirely new object.

Reference types are copied by reference. when you copy one, you are actually copying a reference to some storage location.

String is a value type, but you're trying to make it behave like a reference type.

You can create a class with a String property and then use an array of that class:

```
public class StringWrapper
{
    public String Value {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
   public void SomeMethod()
   {
       StringWrapper[] array = new StringWrapper[3];
       var x = new StringWrapper() { Value="X"; }
       var y = new StringWrapper() { Value="y"; }
       var z = new StringWrapper() { Value="z"; }

       array[0] = x;
       array[1] = y;
       array[2] = z;

       array[0].Value = "xx";
   }
}
```

If you change x.Value, then array[0].Value will also change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using

```
Dictionary<string,string>
```

instead:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Answer (score 0):

By Reading the comment I reached goal :)

backuping the Enemy Last Know Position... actually I'm doing it on this way.
If you have a better solution, show it ^_^

```
    if (EnemyLKP != EnemyLKPBackup[2])
        {
            EnemyLKPBackup[1] = EnemyLKPBackup[2];
            EnemyLKPBackup[0] = EnemyLKPBackup[1];
            EnemyLKPBackup[2] = EnemyLKP;
        }
```